# Unable to install DBD::mysql on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, perl

I am unable to get DBD::mysql installed on Ubuntu 20.04. I get the following error:

> Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL LIB=/home/htm/Lib]
> DVEEDEN/DBD-mysql-4.050.tar.gz
> /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL LIB=/home/htm/Lib -- NOT OK
> Failed during this command:
> DVEEDEN/DBD-mysql-4.050.tar.gz               : writemakefile NO '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL LIB=/home/htm/Lib' returned status 512

As an aside, I'm trying to set up a beta server to mimic a paid web server running Ubuntu 20.04.  They only allow installing Perl modules in the user directory so I did the following:

```
cpan> o conf makepl_arg LIB=/home/htm/Lib
makepl_arg LIB=/home/htm/Lib
```

I have also tried to reset CPAN with o conf init but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by accident.  I had to do this first:

sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

After that I was able to get DBD::mysql installed.